# What is stopping my Visual JVM remote connection?

Tags: centos, java

I have started my application with this settings below:

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote=true
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=43588 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false 
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false 
-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=***.**.***.**
```

The app is running on a Centos machine. I have enabled the port via iptables. I have checked that when I run my application, the port 43588 is shown as listening.

Somehow I still get this error:

> Cannot connect to ***.***.**.**:43588 using service:jmx:rmi///jndi/rmi://***.***.**.**:43588/jmxrmi?

What is my mistake? We are connecting from a windows machine.

Answer (score 0):

look at this:
[How do I fix a 'Failed to retrieve RMIServer stub' JMX error?](https://serverfault.com/questions/308662/how-do-i-fix-a-failed-to-retrieve-rmiserver-stub-jmx-error)

basically java is using yet another connection, which is not configured.